# Search rows for string between characters and sum

Tags: excel

Let’s say I have a column wherein there are blank rows and rows that combine text and numbers. For example, A1 might look like "some text (2)", A2 might contain "some more text (7)", A3 might be blank and A4 look like A1 and A2. I would like to be able to quickly find the sum of the numbers in between the parentheses in column A. I have figured out how to use the MID, LEFT, and FIND functions to extract the values from each string, but getting their sum amounts to an extremely long formula (considering the column might contain as many as twenty such cells). This is what I have been using:

```
SUM(IFERROR(MID(LEFT(A1,FIND(")",A1)-1),FIND("(",A1)+1,LEN(A1)), 0) +
    IFERROR(MID(LEFT(A2,FIND(")",A2)-1),FIND("(",A2)+1,LEN(A2)), 0)+...
```

And so on, down to the last desired row. This is far too tedious. Is there a shorter way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array formula:

```
=SUM(1*IFERROR(MID(LEFT($A$1:$A$20,
     FIND(")",$A$1:$A$20)-1),FIND("(",$A$1:$A$20)+1,LEN($A$1:$A$20)), 0))
```

Enter using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

E.g:

[image]